# Black screen when selecting custom watchface

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, wear-os

I'm playing with Android Wear. I found [this](https://github.com/dwa012/WearBinaryWatchFace) repository which provides Binary Watchface. However, when I install it on AVD emulator and select it the screen goes black. I can switch back to default watchface but a new one doesn't work.

[image: AVD details]
[image: Watchface selection]
[image: Black screen]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Edit your AVD -> Enable "Use Host GPU" worked a bit for me.
The other watch faces are visible and working, but the emulator crashes from time to time

Answer (score 0):

It seems not working on AVD. It works on my G Watch.

The custom watchface is not officially supported yet.
I guess that is how it breaks in an AVD.
The activity is never launched.

Answer (score 0):

Try recreating your AVD with "Use Host GPU" checked.